# Is communication between multiple applications under 'Default Web Site' in IIS 7.0 comes under cross domain?

Tags: iis

Can someone explain briefly that communication between multiple applications under 'Default Web Site' in IIS 7.0 comes under cross domain requests?

or

is it required to host as different web sites by choosing option 'Add Web Site...'?

Comment: What is meant by "cross domain requests"? In what context, a browser?

Comment: I have to deploy WCF 4.0 REST service application and Client application separately.